# How to add a none editable and dispalable original creator tag to a file

Tags: java, vb.net, basic, any

How to add a none editable and dispalable original creator tag to a file to prevent cheating in exams.
I looking for a way, as it says, to stop cheating in exams. A way that the originators name, student/employee no or the like is added to the file in a way that I or anyone else can read it BUT in such a way that regardless of how many times that file is either edited or copied that originators Id stay permanently visible, something like the copyright maker in a boo eg, File created by A.N. Other
Thanks in advance for all help & suggestion or pointers as to available software, if any, all appreciated

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking is generally not possible for generic files.

If you want to apply this to a certain type of file, like a text document or an image, you may find editors for that kind of file that allow to set some fields only when a new document is created, fields that cannot be altered afterwards. This would require the editor to use some kind of encryption so that you cannot simply open the file in a different editor or in binary and change the fields.

Also, this would require to force everybody to use that editor. And still, if the editor supports copy- and pasting, anybody that gets a hold of a document can still copy it's contents into a new file and set the fields then.